# Alternate methods to supply data for machine learning (Other than using CSV files)

Tags: csv, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I have a question which is relating to machine learning application in real world. It might be sounds stupid lol.

I've been self study machine learning for a while and most of the exercise was using the csv file as data source (both processed and raw). I would like to ask is there any other methods other than import csv file to channel/supply data for machine learning?

Example: Streaming Facebook/ Twitter live feed's data for machine learning in real-time, rather than collect old data and stored them into CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data source can be anything. Usually, it's provided as a CSV or JSON file. But in the real world, say you have a website such as Twitter, as you're mentioning, you'd be storing your data in a rational DB such as SQL databases, and for some data you'd be putting them in an in-memory cache.

You can basically utilize both of these to retrieve your data and process it. The thing here is when you have too much data to fit in the memory, you can't really just query everything and process it, in that case, you'll be utilizing some smart algorithms to process data in chunks.

Good thing about some databases such as SQL is that they provide you with a set of functions that you can invoke right in your SQL script to efficiently calculate some data. For example you can get a sum of a column across the whole table or something using `SUM()` function SQL, which allows for efficient and easy data manipulation

Comment: The data to put in memory cache? Is that the training datasets? Assume that machine learning study pattern from in-memory training data and predict on the data from relational DB?

Comment: @不好笑 The training dataset is the dataset that your algorithm would process to form a prediction function. Processing it can either be in chunks, in which for example you load 100 rows from DB, process, them, discard them, and then load another 100, or, process them all in one run, by loading ALL the rows and processing them at once. Which one you will use depends on your algorithm, but you have to consider the fact that sometimes you can't query all the data as that might not fit in RAM, given that variables in programming languages are stored in RAM.

Comment: @不好笑 For example `Batch Gradient Descend` requires processing all data at once, but if you have a super large dataset, then you might use `Stochastic Gradient Descend`, which processes data in chunks.

Comment: Wow nice explanation for utilization of training data set in real world application. :) Now I've the visual on how ML use the training dataset in real world. But how about the testing data, how does it stream in and make use by the ML to generate prediction?

Comment: @不好笑 Typically you would have several datasets, one is a small samples one that you use to check that your code is working, and one much larger dataset you use it to actually train your models, and you have a test dataset that you use to test how accurate your algorithm is. Generally, there are several machine learning techniques, but **to my *small* knowledge**, basically you use your training dataset to calibrate a function you have, so that next time you pass it parameters it can predict better. e.g.: before training the error is 70%, after training the error is 5%